# How to clean the html output of textfield using CKeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a textfield using the wysiwyg http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor text editor module.

If I insert a table in the text then the table is wrapped with the following tags

```
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
```

I thought that the http://drupal.org/project/htmlpurifier module would remove this tags but it doesn't.

How can I remove these lines?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into this, I'm not sure if there is a configuration value to avoid this. I usually end up installing [Empty Paragraph Killer](http://drupal.org/project/emptyparagraphkiller).

> Empty paragraph killer is a filter module, helpful on sites which use
>   WYSIWYG editors.
>
> People often hit the return key twice at the end of a paragraph. Most,
>   if not all site layouts manage the paragraph spacing, so the extra
>   empty paragraphs created can detract from the look and feel of a site.
>   This module filters out the empty paragraphs of all user-entered data
>   on a site. It does so by following the fundamental Drupal way -
>   non-destructively.

Comment: As you said, it works fine. I get those lines removed. Thanks